# Hibernate Envers: can't create custom revision entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to create a custom revision entity and I do exactly what written in the official documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-revisionlog

In separate simple project it works but in my main project I got always the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/hibernate/resource/beans/spi/ManagedBeanRegistry  at
>   org.hibernate.envers.internal.revisioninfo.DefaultRevisionInfoGenerator.resolveRevisionListenerBean(DefaultRevisionInfoGenerator.java:108)

Comment: It looks like you are potentially mixing versions of Hibernate ORM and Envers.  Are you using the same version of both artifacts?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following dependencies solve the problem:

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.4.0.Final'
```

Comment: Fwiw, `hibernate-entitymanager` is nothing more than an empty-jar and should not be required.  It was folded into `hibernate-core` as a part of 5.2.0.Final.